# What's the selection highlight color of an NSTableView?

Tags: macos, colors, nstableview, nscolor

I'm making a completely custom control (NSView), and I want to use the user's preferred highlight color for part of it when it's selected, like NSTableView does.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to get this.  The NSColor documentation only lists one (non-deprecated) user-chosen color, `selectedTextBackgroundColor`, and NSTableView uses a much darker or more saturated (?) color for the selection highlight.

I've tried a couple things, like turning up the saturation (fails for gray), and darkening with `shadow()` (looks bad, and not like NSTableView), but I'm not an expert on colors.

Does anybody know what NSTableView is doing, to get this color?  Is there any way to access it more directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSColor.alternateSelectedControlColor` is what you want.  The comments in `NSTableView.h` are somewhat out of date (referring to the color being light blue, when it isn't any more).  I don't see the constants in NSColor being deprecated... not sure what you are talking about? (Maybe a documentation bug?  When in doubt, look at the headers...)

Comment: In the "Color Programming Topics" guide, section "Accessing System Colors" says: "Note: A number of system colors, while still valid, are no longer meaningful under Aqua. These include any of the ones with "control" in their name."

Comment: The color didn't look correct in the Color palette, but I think there's a bug with updating those.  It does look correct in my application.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1533135-alternateselectedcontrolcolor says alternateSelectedControlColor is deprecated and to use selectedContentBackgroundColor instead.